# How to make dotted border even around a circle in css?

Tags: html, css, border

I have my code on codepen:
https://codepen.io/matejcsok/pen/PONJgP?editors=0100

I have a task that makes one circle, and multiple borders around it, but the outermost dotted border's circles are not in even distance at the top.
[image]
I am allowed to use only one div in the html code.

```css
body{
  width: 500px;
  height:500px;
}
div{
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    left: 250px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px green;
}
div:after {
    content: '';
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 5px dashed pink;
    top: -40px;
    left: -40px;
    right: -40px;
    bottom: -40px;
    background: white;
    z-index: -1;
}
div:before {
    content: '';
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 7px dotted chocolate;
    top: -60px;
    left: -60px;
    right: -60px;
    bottom: -60px;
    background: white;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

The distance between the dots is fixed. The browser does not optimize the distance to render evenly, whether you make the `div` into a circle or not.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it is rendered good in internet explorer, firefox, edge

Comment: In FF 48 OSX the dots are not rendered at all.

Answer (score 0):

not sure on your exact requirements, but from my point of view I would reduce the border-width to 2 or 3 px as the dashed/dotted lines are still visible, with the spacing issue on top becoming less visible.